# Symfony Profiler phpactiverecord

Tags: symfony, activerecord, profiler, silex

I'm using "silex/silex": "~2.0". and  "silex/web-profiler": "^2.0", and phpactiverecord.org.
I made some little provider to integrate AR to Silex.
The question is how to integrate AR queries to WebProfiler.. Is It possible, and what is the right way to do this.

Comment: okay, found this https://github.com/Sorien/silex-dbal-profiler/tree/master/src/Sorien service on git, it's good example. i did the same for AR, soon i will upload it to git. maybe someone will need it too.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any solution, so I made it myself
https://github.com/timtimosh/php-activerecord-service-provider here is the implementation activerecord for silex2.

and here is the activerecord implementation for profiler - now it showing list of queries that you've made. 
https://github.com/timtimosh/php-activerecord-profiler-service
letter i will upload it to packagist for installing via composer.

I'm planing to make some activerrecord silex2 crud generator letter.